# Spring Boot Maven project giving error after importing on STS-4

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, spring-tool-suite

I have the IDE Spring Tool Suite 4 and I imported the Spring Boot project generated by JHipster using the option "Import > Existing Maven project", however, the project show error in the first line which is just a comment in **package-info.java** and because of that the project not run when I try initialize by Boot Dashboard in IDE.

The IDE show this erros:

- The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for javax.servlet.ServletException. Fix the build path then try building this project;
- The type javax.servlet.ServletException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

[image: Errors in STS]

I tried:

- project > clean;
- right click in project > Run > Maven clean;
- right click in project > Maven > Update project;

Usually this steps work, but not in this project.
When i open the terminal and write `mvn clean package` and run the .war or execute ./mvnw the API works.

Why does this error occur in STS 4 if the terminal compiles without problems?

Comment: there are a few things missing from the latest STS 4.2.1 release with regards to support for war-packaged boot apps. Can you try a latest nightly build of the STS 4.2.2 distribution from https://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/STS4/nightly-distributions.html to see if that helps? And if not, fiel an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues? That would be great!

Comment: I did the test but it did not work.

Comment: can you file an issue and attach the sample application that you generated? We will take a look.

Comment: Try to use jdk instead of jre as library in project build path. Try to add servlet dependency in pom and update maven project.

Comment: I ran tests with Eclipse and opened an issue in the STS project on GitHub. In Eclipse the problem also occurs and in issue they said that it is a bug in the Maven plugin. Now I think I'll have to use another IDE :/